# ruby on rails filtering pg_search_scope v2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and I need help figuring out how to amend an existing db query. I'm using old versions, which I cannot update: Ruby 2.2.3p173, and Rails 4.0.2.

I want to filter the existing query results to remove records which do not have any videos. The model hierarchy I think is: Artist, AlbumGroup, Album, Track, Video.

To clarify: I want artists with at least 1 video, from the model association artist->AlbumGroup->albums->tracks->videos (not artist->videos).

The existing query is contained in model Artist:

```
require_dependency "tagging"
require_dependency "similar"
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artforms, through: :taggings
  has_many :similars, foreign_key: "similar_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :similar_artists, through: :similars, source: :similar_to
  has_many :reverse_similars, foreign_key: "similar_to_id", class_name: "Similar", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :similar_to_artists, through: :reverse_similars, source: :similar
  has_many :memberships, foreign_key: "member_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships, source: :membership
  has_many :group_members, foreign_key: "membership_id", class_name: "Membership", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :group_members, source: :member
  has_many :users, through: :followed_artists
  has_many :videos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :audios, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :metrics, through: :audios
  has_many :releases, foreign_key: 'artist_id', class_name: "AlbumGroup"
  has_many :albums
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :album_groups, through: :collaborations
  mount_uploader :mugshot, MugshotUploader
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :for_name,
      against: :name,
      using: { tsearch: {threshold: '1', dictionary: 'simple', tsvector_column: 'tsv_name', prefix: true, normalization: 2}},
      ranked_by: "(artists.popularity / 50 * :tsearch) + :tsearch"
end
```

I want to add something like the following to filter out the records which do not have any videos: (to the query):

```
if: artist.releases.albums.tracks.videos.count > 1
```

Or the Artist model maybe?:

```
scope :valid, -> {where("video_count > 1")}
```

The other code for the different models is below:

```
class AlbumGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :artists, through: :collaborations
  has_many :albums
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artforms, through: :taggings
  mount_uploader :artwork, MugshotUploader
  def as_json options={}
    {
      id: id,
      title: title
    }
  end
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album_group
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :tracks
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_tracks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_tracks
  belongs_to :audio
  belongs_to :video
  has_many :videos
  has_many :audios
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artforms, through: :taggings
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist
  default_scope order: "position ASC"
  after_save :cache_columns

  def cache_columns
    if image_url.nil?
      img = album.album_group.artwork_url(:tiny)
      unless img.nil?
        update_column(:image_url,img)
      end
    end
    if artist_name.nil?
      if artist_id
        name = Artist.find(artist_id).name
        update_column(:artist_name,name)
      end
    end
    if album_name.nil?
      if album_id
        title = Album.find(album_id).title
        update_column(:album_name,title)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :track
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :playlists, through: :tracks, order: "tracks.position ASC"
  scope :valid, -> {where("flag_count < 2").order("score DESC") }
  scope :flagged, -> {where("flag_count > ?", 1) }
#   validates :url, uniqueness: {scope: :artist_id}
end
```

Comment: Do you have some error ocurring? This scope :valid, -> {where("video_count > 1")} looks ok to me as a solution

Comment: The scope code doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't appear to work. I was guessing at code based on various googling, so I don't know if "video_count" is valid or not

Comment: you want to find the elements without videos and delete it?

Comment: no, it's just a read-only query, leaving the data untouched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gabriel, I've added a raw SQL query to artists_controller.rb, which looks like:

```
  def index
    #artists = Artist.for_name(params[:name])
    artists = Artist.find_by_sql ["SELECT artists.*, ((artists.popularity / 50 * (ts_rank((artists.tsv_name), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || ? || ' ''' || ':*')), 2))) + (ts_rank((artists.tsv_name), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || ? || ' ''' || ':*')), 2))) AS pg_search_rank FROM artists " +
      "JOIN album_groups on (artists.id = album_groups.artist_id) " +
      "JOIN tracks on (tracks.album_group_id = album_groups.id) " +
      "JOIN videos on (videos.track_id = tracks.id) " +
      "WHERE (((artists.tsv_name) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || ? || ' ''' || ':*')))) " +
      "GROUP BY artists.id " +
      "ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, artists.id ASC", params[:name], params[:name], params[:name]]
    render json: artists, each_serializer: SimpleArtistSerializer
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord's `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods give you the ability to define scopes directly on the association. This way, you can customize the SQL that is generated when you access the association.

let’s say you wanted to define a scope on the Artist model which returns all artists who have zero videos. In Rails 5, to find all artists that have no videos, you can use `left_outer_joins`

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  scope :with_zero_videos, -> { left_outer_joins(:videos).where(videos: {id: nil}) }
end
```

Another good solution is to use `includes` like this:

```
Artist.includes(:videos).where(videos: { videos_id: nil })
```

You can choose the one you like the most!

Hope it helped.

Comment: ok, so comments aren't great for writing code in.... I added artists = Artist.include(:videos).where(videos: {videos_id: nil}) to my ArtistsController and I get an error: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)

Comment: The scope solution doesn't cause errors but doesn't affect the generated SQL query, which is:  SELECT "artists".*, ((artists.popularity / 50 * (ts_rank(("artists"."tsv_name"), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'oasis' || ' ''' || ':*')), 2))) + (ts_rank(("artists"."tsv_name"), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'oasis' || ' ''' || ':*')), 2))) AS pg_search_rank FROM "artists" WHERE ((("artists"."tsv_name") @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'oasis' || ' ''' || ':*')))) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "artists"."id" ASC

Comment: So I am a little lost here, I thought that you only need a query that retrieve all artists with empty videos. What is the relation between the scope query and this SQL query you showed?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps my English was a little ambiguous "I want to filter the existing query results to remove records which do not have any videos", meaning I want to query for artists with at least 1 video (and it's the artist->AlbumGroup->albums->tracks->videos association, NOT artist->videos). I hope this is clearer

Comment: is pg_search_scope a requirement? I think you need to perform some joins, and pg_search gems says that Right now, searching deeper than one association away is not supported. Take a look here : https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search